# why is my list not rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

by default it shows `10 elements`, but when i change the input it does not update, below is the code and fiddle.

JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
    $scope.listItems = 10;
    $scope.newTotal = function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.lisItemsTotal})
    }
    $scope.lisItemsTotal = function(num) {
        return new Array($scope.listItems);   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0dwmqn8y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that after changing the input `$scope.listItems` is a string, as the input type is text. Change it to number and all will work. Working plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/yv0z9q8L/

```
<input type="number" name="red" ng-model="listItems" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().newTotal()">
```

Also note, that you don't need `onchange` attribute at all here, however I am unsure whether this is a good thing. Using a function in for ng-repeat is quite dangerous unless you know what you are doing, as this function will be called in each digest cycle. If you are planning to loop over large set of data, it will pretty much kill your performance.

Personally, I would rather go with:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <input type="number" name="red" ng-model="itemCount">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
    </ul>               
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
  $scope.$watch('itemCount', function(val) {
    $scope.items = Array.new(val)
  });
  $scope.itemCount = 10;
});
```

plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/m1zq3zqv/1/

Answer (score 0):

The data, that you get from the input field is a string, so you can either change the input type to number or apply a bit of parsing in your code by changing the following line

`return new Array($scope.listItems);`

to this:

`return new Array(parseInt($scope.listItems));`